# Swift: binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two 'Comparable' operands

Tags: swift

I have a protocol defined that has within it a function that returns an associated type that the user can define in their protocol implementation.  The only requirement is that the associated type conform to Comparable.

I have another class that uses elements that conform to this protocol.  The issue I'm running into is that the compiler is complaining that I can't compare elements of the associated type, even though I've specifically marked them as Comparable in the protocol definition.  Anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

```
protocol MyElement {

    associatedtype T : Comparable
    func getValue() -> T

}

class MyNode {

    init(elements:[any MyElement]) {
    
        // Sort the elements
        let sortedElements = elements.sorted(by: { ( a:any MyElement, b:any MyElement ) -> Bool in
            let aT = a.getValue()
            let bT = b.getValue()
        
            return aT < bT
        })
    
    }

}
```

The compiler complains at the line **aT < bT**:

```
binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two 'Comparable' operands
```

Comment: two elements that conform to Comparable doesn't mean they are the same element type. How would you expect to compare a string and an integer?

Comment: Fair.  How could I rewrite this to enforce that all elements in the MyNode initializer are working with this same associated type?

Comment: You could make your own "type-erased" version of `Comparable`, that you could call `AnyComparable`. Look at how Swift took `Hashable` and added `AnyHashable` to the toolset, a type-erased version without the generic `Self` type. That would solve your problem.

Comment: @ShaunBudhram `init<T: MyElement>(elements: [T])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<` operator applies to two values of *a single type that conforms to Comparable* — not to two things designated merely as Comparable. A protocol does not conform to itself.

The use of `any` with MyElement doesn't affect this basic fact about the Comparable-constrained generic placeholder T. Since MyElement is generic over T, we would have to know that the two different MyElement-conforming objects you propose to sort resolve their T to the *same type* as one another — and in the code you wrote, we don't know that, so the compiler balks.